# How to find number of each line starting with specific parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, list, api, youtube

So I'm trying to use the YouTube API to extract some info about each video in a playlist, I've already used to API to get hold of the whole information and I've split it per line , just need to know how to find the number of each line which starts with "videoId" so that I can go from there.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: When you say _the number of each line_ you mean the index in the array?

Comment: @Trey nothing yet, I'm working on it

Comment: @CNuts yeah , sorry for the bad wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StartsWith()` which return true if the string starts with the value given

```
List<int> arrayIndex = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("videoId"))
    {
        arrayIndex.Add(i);
    }
}
```

`arrayIndex` will have the index of each line that started with `"videoId"`

Comment: @frazzlee Haha don't worry about that it's not needed, just happy I could help out :)

Comment: ah no I will haha, p.s. I've been using your math app for quite some time now(few weeks now), whenever I'm bored or waiting somewhere I load it up :D,

Comment: @frazzlee That's great too hear :D There's a big update coming up soon :)